# Total output of `du` is less than individual folders

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, nas

How can the total output from `du` be 1.1T when the folder home is 1.7T and i-data is 1.4T? That together should already total more than 3 TB.

```
/ # du /* -shc
1.0M    /bin
0   /dev
0   /e-data
1.4M    /etc
192.8M  /firmware
1.7T    /home
1.4T    /i-data
8.0K    /init
6.2M    /lib
0   /linuxrc
28.0K   /mnt
1.7M    /opt
0   /proc
120.3M  /ram_bin
0   /root
4.0M    /sbin
0   /sys
636.0K  /tmp
118.0M  /usr
5.4M    /var
1.1T    total
```

It even gets weirder.

I decides to run `du` inside the home directory:

```
/ # du /home/* -shc
0   /home/joopjr
0   /home/pager
0   /home/server4you
1.7T    /home/shares
1.7T    total
```

This seems logical, the shares folder has 1.7T of content and the total also is 1.7T. But:

```
/ # du /home/shares/* -shc
685.6G  /home/shares/13006
685.6G  /home/shares/17611
685.6G  /home/shares/23008
du: /home/shares/24324: No such file or directory
8.9G    total
```

According to `du` the folders inside the shares folder are 685G each but the total of these 3 folders is 8.9G?

I'm running the command on a Zyxel Nas. The Nas has 4 bays with HDD. Those 4 drives are part of a volume group with an (raid5) ext4 partition.

Can someone explain this behavior?

---

Edit 14 december:
After the comment from muru I've tried it on a different folder with `-hcd 1` instead of `-shc` and it still gives a wrong total. The folder Joop is 1.5T alone but it claims the total is 1.4T

```
~ # du /i-data/sysvol/ -hcd 1
225.8M  /i-data/sysvol/music
74.4G   /i-data/sysvol/public
856.5G  /i-data/sysvol/server
84.8M   /i-data/sysvol/.system
28.0K   /i-data/sysvol/photo
1.5T    /i-data/sysvol/Joop
12.0K   /i-data/sysvol/document
16.0K   /i-data/sysvol/raspberry
13.8M   /i-data/sysvol/.PKG
133.7G  /i-data/sysvol/software
685.6G  /i-data/sysvol/backup
104.7G  /i-data/sysvol/video
1.1M    /i-data/sysvol/admin
70.0G   /i-data/sysvol/lost+found
1.4T    /i-data/sysvol/
1.4T    total
```

Comment: `*` won't match directories or files with names that start with `.`. If your `du` has the `-d` option, use that: `du -hcd 1 /home` instead of `du -shc /home/*`

Comment: @muru I've tried it on a different folder and it still gives wrong totals. Folder Joop is 1.5T alone, total is 1.4 T
`~ # du /i-data/sysvol/ -hcd 1
225.8M /i-data/sysvol/music
74.4G /i-data/sysvol/public
856.5G /i-data/sysvol/server
84.8M /i-data/sysvol/.system
28.0K /i-data/sysvol/photo
1.5T /i-data/sysvol/Joop
12.0K /i-data/sysvol/document
16.0K /i-data/sysvol/raspberry
13.8M /i-data/sysvol/.PKG
133.7G /i-data/sysvol/software
685.6G /i-data/sysvol/backup
104.7G /i-data/sysvol/video
1.1M /i-data/sysvol/admin
70.0G /i-data/sysvol/lost+found
1.4T /i-data/sysvol/
1.4T total`

Comment: Please edit the question to add long output like that. It's unreadable in the comment.

Comment: @muru I'm sorry, I didn't know it would remove al new line characters. I've edited the question.